# SQL Server 2014 : MAX and HAVING query

Tags: sql-server

Self-taught novice here

I am trying to return a set of values within 52 weeks of the latest Date in table EmplUDABreakdown.

```
DECLARE @AVGEarn TABLE 
   (
     EmployeeCode VARCHAR(12)
     ,AVGEarn DECIMAL(12,2)
     ,Weeks INT
   )

INSERT INTO @AVGEarn
   SELECT 
       E.EmployeeCode,
       (SELECT SUM(EMPL.Amount) 
        FROM EMPLUDABreakdown EMPL 
        WHERE EMPL.EmployeeCode = E.EmployeeCode 
          AND EMPL.UserDefinedAccumulatorCode = 'AVGEARN' 
          AND DATE <= MAX(EMPL.[Date]) 
          AND DATE >= DATEADD(WEEK,-52,MAX(EMPL.[Date]))) AS AVGEarn,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EMPL.[Date]) 
        FROM EMPLUDABreakdown EMPL 
        WHERE EMPL.EmployeeCode = E.EmployeeCode 
          AND EMPL.UserDefinedAccumulatorCode = 'AVGHRS' 
          AND DATE <= MAX(EMPL.[Date])  
          AND DATE >= DATEADD(WEEK,-52,MAX(EMPL.[Date])+1)) AS Weeks
   FROM 
       Employee E
   WHERE 
       E.TerminationDate IS NULL
   ORDER BY 
       E.EmployeeCode

   SELECT * FROM @AVGEarn
```

I get an error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

I changed to...

```
   (SELECT SUM(EMPL.Amount) 
    FROM EMPLUDABreakdown EMPL 
    WHERE EMPL.EmployeeCode = E.EmployeeCode 
      AND EMPL.UserDefinedAccumulatorCode = 'AVGEARN' 
    GROUP BY EMPL.[Date]
    HAVING DATE <= MAX(EMPL.[Date]) AND DATE >= DATEADD(WEEK,-52,MAX(EMPL.[Date]))) AS AVGEarn
```

and got the following message

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Your query is returning more than one row, because you're grouping it. What do you actually want? One row with the total, several rows with the groupings? the sum row that has the biggest date?

Comment: Hi there.  I actually want one row returned with the SUM(Earnings) and COUNT(Weeks) within the last 52 weeks from the latest week.  Thank you